# What will happen if one unlock all the chakra in his/her body?

Tags: chakras

https://images.app.goo.gl/rsRm9ahmrxgMem466

So what will happen if one unlock all 7 of these chakra.

Comment: You will awaken what is called the Kundalini shakti, a quiet snake resting at the muladhara chakra. It’s all known as making one’s virya urdhvagami. Basically a form of yoga where one can gain enlightenment.

Comment: Yes, it answered my question. thanks